# AWS EC2: How to process queue with 100 parallel ec2 instances?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto

(ubuntu 12.04). I envision some sort of Queue to put thousands of tasks, and have the ec2 isntances plow through it in parallel (100 ec2 instances) where each instance handles one task from the queue.

Also, each ec2 instance to use the image I provide, which will have the binaries and software installed on it for use.

Essentially what I am trying to do is, run 100 processing (a python function using packages that depend on binaries installed on that image) in parallel on Amazon's EC2 for an hour or less, shut them all off, and repeat this process whenever it is needed.

Is this doable? I am using Python Boto to do this.

Comment: Can you give us more detail on what you're doing? What is the output of all these tasks are what are you doing with that output?

Comment: I am running computer vision on each item in the queue. the output needs to be stored on s3 bucket. basically, I need a way to fire up a custom image containing the computer vision library installed, and need 100 instances of this running at some point for parallel processing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like it might be easier to with EMR.

You mentioned in comments you are doing computer vision. You can make your job hadoop friendly by preparing a file where each line a base64 encoding of the image file.

You can prepare a simple bootstrap script to make sure each node of the cluster has your software installed. Hadoop streaming will allow you to use your image processing code as is for the job (instead of rewriting in java).

When your job is over, the cluster instances will be shut down. You can also specify your output be streamed directly to an S3 bucket, its all baked in. EMR is also cheap, 100 m1.medium EC2 instances running for an hour will only cost you around 2 dollars according to the most recent pricing: http://aws.amazon.com/elasticmapreduce/pricing/

Comment: that looks like it will do the job, I wonder if each of those m1 instances have unique ip address. Also they do not have t1 micro instance but looks like the m1.small could do the job. another concern is whether FIFO order can be maintained. for example 100 images on s3 bucket, must result in the exact same order in the resulting s3 bucket. I guess SQS is not needed with EMR?

Comment: "Hadoop streaming will allow you to use your image processing code as is for the job (instead of rewriting in java)." how can I do this?

Comment: The basic idea with hadoop streaming is you just write a script in any language that reads from STDIN and writes to STDOUT. There is good documentation: http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/streaming.html As for the FIFO order that is not really going to be applicable here, conceptually all the images are going to be processed at the same time (whether this actually happens depends on number of instances/size of input). You can always sort your output by the key, that could fulfill your need of having the data in a certain order. Each instance will have a unique IP.

Answer (score 3):

This is doable.  You should look into using [SQS](https://aws.amazon.com/sqs/).  Jobs are placed on a queue and the worker instances pop jobs off the queue and perform the appropriate work.  As a job is completed, the worker deletes the job from the queue so no job is run more than once.

You can configure your instances using user-data at boot time or you can bake AMIs with all of your software pre-installed.  I recommend [Packer](http://www.packer.io/) for baking AMIs as it works really well and is very scriptable so your AMIs can be rebuilt consistently as things need to be changed.

For turning on and off lots of instances, look into using [AutoScaling](https://aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/).  Simply set the group's desired capacity to the number of worker instances you want running and it will take care of the rest.